# ajaxSubmitButton doing multiple submits

Tags: ajax, yii

So the problem is i got form and submit it via ajax. I made it alot of times before and it always was working, and now idk what to do.

So more info. Form config:

```
 <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
       'id'=>'user-form',
       "action"=>"#",
       'enableClientValidation'=>true,
       'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
       'clientOptions'=>array(
           'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
       ),
       'htmlOptions'=>array(
       ),
));
?>
```

Button:

```
<?php 
        $id='applications-form_submit_' . rand(1, 255);
        echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton($model->isNewRecord ? UserModule::t('Create') : UserModule::t('Save'), Yii::app()->request->url, array(
                'type' => 'post',
                'dataType' => 'json',
                'beforeSend'=>'function(){$("body").undelegate("#'.$id.'","click");}',
                'success' =>
                'js:function (e) {
                    clear_errors();
                    if (e.status=="success"){
                       if (e.redirect=="here"){
                         notification(e.message);
                       }   
                       else window.location.replace(e.redirect);
                    } else {
                        $.each(e, function(key, val) {
                             $("#user-form #"+key+"_em_").text(val+" ");
                             $("#user-form #"+key+"_em_").parent(".error_wrapter").addClass("error");
                             $("#user-form #"+key+"_em_").css("display","block");

                        });
                    }
                }',
            ), array(
                'id' => $id,

            ));?>
```

I think controller code is not important, cause click make 2 requests to it.

What already tried to do:
1. Add onsubmit="return false;" to form.
2. Add preventDefault().
3. Change action.
It doesn't work, so its not form issue.

What tried to do with button: 
1. Add $('body').unbind() in beforeSave and success.
2. Add undelegate().

Doesnt help also.

Yii version is 1.1.14.

Comment: try with: 'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,

Comment: @Daniel Vaquero it's same.

Comment: Is the page refreshing? In other words, is the submission done once by ajax, once normally (non-ajax)?

Comment: It's already solved. Problem was in double bind of submit. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should've posted the controller code, I think you have a redirect there in your action.

```
function actionAjax..() {
    ...
    $this->redirect('action');
    ...
}
```

Comment: Nope, redirect done with js and depends on action. Problem already solved. Thanks for response.